# Literature Request. Kinetic Fokker-Planck (Kramers) Equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, stochastic-processes, physics, stochastic-differential-equations

Does anyone have some introductory literature on the Kinetic Fokker-Planck equation? Or can point me to any cornerstone results.

Comment: I don't have time for a detailed reply but the new book "Elements of Nonequilibrium Statistical Mechanics" by Balakrishnan is quite good. The classics are "The Fokker-Planck equation" by Risken and "Handbook of Stochastic Methods" by Gardiner. "Nonequilibrium Statistical Mechanics II" by Kubo is also good. These latter three books are nowhere near as pedagogical as the new Balakrishnan book.

Comment: Recently I have been reading the 4th edition of "A modern course in statistical physics" by Reichl and it has quite a nice chapter on the topic as well, although it is a bit brief.